# Binding to progress bar

Tags: angular

Any idea how to bind the data to progress bar in Angular2? {{}} does not work on the existing attribute like aria-valuenow or value for progress tag. Below is the bootstrap one.

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
    <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update with more details**

update.service.ts : this is to create the obseverable,

```
  public _progress$: Observable<number>;
  private _progress: number = 0;
  private _progressObserver: Observer<number>;
  constructor(private _http:Http, private _configurationService: ConfigurationService,private _authenservice:AuthenticationService) {
    this._progress$ = new Observable(observer => {
      this._progressObserver = observer
    });
  }
....
this._progressObserver.next(this._progress); // this is to push in the progress number from xhr.upload.onprogress
```

home.component.ts: the component where display the progress bar,

```
  private  _uploadProgressStatus:Observable<number>;// as "asyn" only takes in the promise of observable, I plan to feed _uploadProgressStatus in

  constructor(private _videoManagementService:VideoManagementService,
              private _uploadService:UploadService) {
    console.info('HomeComponent  Mounted Successfully');
    this._uploadProgressStatus = this._uploadService._progress$; 
 this._uploadProgressStatus.subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log('progress = '+data/100);
  }); //if subscribe to this._uploadProgressStatus, no values are received...
this._uploadService._progress$.subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log('progress = '+data/100);
  });
  } // if subscribe to this._uploadService._progress$ ,numbers are received.
```

home.component.html

```
  <h4>Uploading...{{ _uploadProgressStatus | async | percent}}</h4>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" [style.width]="_uploadProgressStatus | async | percent" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
      <h4>{{ _uploadProgressStatus | async | percent}} </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is not working. So the question is how to create the observable in home.component.ts to receive the numbers ?

in html update _uploadProgressStatus to _uploadService._progress$ is also not working

Answer (score 3):

```js
    var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 200);
    var a=1;
    function myTimer() {
      a++;
      if(a>=99){a=1;}
      document.getElementById("progress-bar").style.width = a+"%";
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a+"% Complete";
    }


   function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
   }
  /* function myStartFunction() {
    myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 200);
   }*/
```

```css
    #progress-bar{
    background-color:#00CC00;
    }
```

```html
   <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" style="width:70%" id="progress-bar">
        <span id="demo">70% Complete</span>
        
      </div>
    </div>
<button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop</button>

<!--<button onclick="myStartFunction()">Start</button>-->
```

Comment: if Start  .......................................

function myStartFunction() {
    myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 200);
}

<button onclick="myStartFunction()">Start</button>

Comment: Thanks. yes, set interval definitely can work. I am more looking at whether there is any way in Angular2

Answer (score 3):

It should be pretty simple. Here's an example of a working component:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-special-component',
  template: `
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" [style.width]="myProgress | percent">
        <span class="sr-only">{{ myProgress | percent" }} Complete</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class MySpecialComponent {
  // A number from 0 to 1
  private myProgress: number

  constructor() {}
}
```

The important bit is here: `[style.width]="myProgress | async | percent"`
This is a one way binding against the CSS `width` property. The `async` pipe ensures the value remains updated even as `myProgress` changes. The `percent` pipe transforms the value to a string like `70%`.

---

A more advanced example- You will likely want to use something like `Input()` or even a Rx.js observable to represent the `myProgress` variable. This will even work with promises. You will want to use the `async` pipe in this situation:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-special-component',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" [style.width]="myProgress | async | percent">
        <span class="sr-only">{{ myProgress | async | percent" }} Complete</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class MySpecialComponent {
  // A number from 0 to 1
  Input() myProgress: number

  constructor() {}
}
```

Now if you were to change this value elsewhere, say in a parent component:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core'
import { MySpecialComponent } from './my-special-component.ts'

@Component({
  selector: 'root-component',
  directives: [ MySpecialComponent ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
  template: `
    <my-special-component [myProgress]="rootProgress"</my-special-component>
  `
})
export class RootComponent {
  // A number from 0 to 1
  private rootProgress: number

  constructor() {
    this.rootProgress = 0.5
  }
}
```

^^ in this example we have 2 components: MySpecialComponent as the child, and RootComponent as the parent. As you can see, MySpecialComponent doesn't have the `myProgress` value explicitly set anywhere. However, it will resolve as 0.5 because we set it in RootComponent and bind that to MySpecialComponent's `myProgress` Input() binding.

Comment: Thanks. there is an error thrown out from the codes.  Invalid argument '1' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' in [_uploadProgressStatus | async | percent in HomeComponent@251:53]

Comment: @Hammer Oops, I'll update this. I think I know what the issue is.

Comment: I updated it. Haven't tested any of this code so if you try it, let me know how it works!

Comment: Thanks Nick. I follow your approach to feed in the observable to async and percent. Pls refer to the update on the post. The problem is in the observable part.

Comment: @Hammer why not use `_uploadService._progress$` directly? (in the template, that is)

Comment: Nick, the issue for not receiving data has been solved. but the progress bar animation is not there. However, when I see the log it reaches 100%, I click on the progress bar, the progress bar quickly moves from 0% to 100%. It seems the aync drawing is not working. Any idea?

Comment: have to click the progress bar to see the current % , otherwise, the progress bar won't be auto updated

Comment: @Hammer mm that's annoying. I remember running into this issue before, let me check my code

Comment: @Hammer Updated. I changed 2 lines: you'll want to include `ChangeDetectionStrategy` from ng2 core and set the change detection strategy to `OnPush`. I added this to the child component (MySpecialComponent) which should work; if not, move these changes to RootComponent instead.